# Expo app crashes on andriod emulator when using navigation stack

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I just entered react native about a week ago and I just stumbled on this problem.

Every time I connect the navigation stack/drawer to my home app.js and then I run the expo app it shutdowns unexpectedly. Sometimes it shows an error but for less than a second then closes. But most times it never shows an error before closing.

I was able to capture an error but I'm not sure if it was the error that briefly shows. This was the error

```
unexpected identifier 'n'. Expected either in or if in enumeration syntax.
```

I have no idea where this error comes from.

My App.js

```
    import Home from './screens/Home';
// import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import Navigator from './routes/HomeStack'

export default function App() {
  const [fontLoaded] = useFonts({
    'nunitoBold': require('./assets/fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf'),
    'nunitoRegular': require('./assets/fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf'),
  })
    // const [fontLoaded,setFontLoaded] = useState(false)

    if (!fontLoaded) {
      return (
        <AppLoading/>
      )
    }else{
      return (
        <Home/>
      )
    }
}
```

My HomeStack.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Details from "../screens/Details";
import Home from "../screens/Home";

const screens = {
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
    },
    ReviewDetails: {
        screen: Details,
    },
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
       headerStyle:{ backgroundColor: '#f00' },
       headerTintColor: '#444'
    }
})

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

My Home.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';

export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([
    { title: 'Zelda, Breath of Fresh Air', rating: 5, body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '1' },
    { title: 'Gotta Catch Them All (again)', rating: 4, body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '2' },
    { title: 'Not So "Final" Fantasy', rating: 3, body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '3' },
  ]);
  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <FlatList 
        data={reviews}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ReviewDetails', item)}>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Also this worked yesterday perfectly. I just started receiving such errors just today and I hadn't even touched my code.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "gamezone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: That error is saying that somewhere you are using a for loop but instead of saying "for (const something [IN | OF] someArray)" you are using an invalid keyword (something other than IN or OF). Search your code for for loops and see if you can find the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem came from me installing the drawer navigation and stack navigation together. Also I came from the netninja youtube channel. Uninstalling that fix my problem  and following the updated way to install it.